# how does explaining why unoptimized code is a good default not answer why a compiler doesn't optimize by default?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I gave [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912621/optimization-of-subsequent-calls-to-integer-division-and-modulo-remainder/15912755#15912755) in response to

> Why isn't this kind of optimization a default?

in that question.  If compilers and optimizers were perfect and debuggers could reverse-engineer code, optimization would be a universal default.  But compilers don't always generate correct code, optimizers don't always preserve semantics, and debuggers can't always figure out what part(s) of a optimized program any given instruction relates to.

A commenter called those assertions false and the answer non sequitur, and the answer was deleted.

Comment: Okay.. I don't see a question in this though..

Comment: Well, you didn't answer the question. The question asks for how to avoid multiple calls to `idivl`. You gave an answer about how compilers are complicated.

Comment: @Seth it's in the title.

Comment: @Mysticial -- He asked multiple questions. I believe I answered one of them, specifically the first one he asked, the one I quoted here.

Comment: Did you post the answer again? I don't recommend that, even if it was deleted in a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am the moderator who deleted that answer, based on community flagging. I did so largely, but not exclusively, due to this quote from the end of the question:

> **Also, and perhaps even more important**, is there a way, as a programmer, to manually extract these 2 values (quotient and remainder) guaranteeing that only 1 integer division is performed by the CPU?

(emphasis in original)

And then partially based on this series of sub-questions:

> Why isn't this kind of optimization a default? What is the use of calling div twice in a row? Can this optimization change the behaviour of a program in any way?

I can sort of see your argument, now, that you believed that to be answer to the first of the sub-queries, but it actually didn't look like one to me; It pretty much just said, "it's all a mess and too complicated to explain", *as I read it when reviewing the flag*. That made it arguably worthy of a comment, but the post was far too long for that.

More importantly to me, though; you did not answer what the OP said was the most important part of their question.

I see you have posted another, similar answer. I won't be doing anything to that one myself. I'm open to being wrong on my handling of that flag, but I don't think I was, right now.

---

Also, incidentally; the deletion had *nothing at all* to do with whether the information contained in the answer was correct or not. Moderators do not make such judgments.

Comment: I can see the original was unclear -- muddied, even. that's why I posted the new one explicitly pointing out which of his questions I answered. Other people had already answered his main question, it seems to me him having answers for all of his questions is better than for just some of them, apparently that view's not so widely shared as I'd thought.

Comment: @jthill Actually, I think your new answer makes things more clear. I doubt I would delete that one if it was flagged.

Comment: @Andrew Barber: can you elaborate what was the reason for flagging?

Comment: The specifics of flags are irrelevant when a moderator agrees or takes action mentioned/requested in the flags. @car

Comment: @random: I disagree. I guess what I'm trying to say is that it seems likely that it was flagged by the commenter, the same that said it was a non-sequitur, as a wrong answer. And since the commenter must be right (he used latin, right?) the moderator sided with him. In this case decidedly not irrelevant.

Comment: @carlosdc You should be extremely careful about making assumptions like that. Both of your assumptions, actually. As I noted in my post, Moderators do *not* delete answers due to incorrect information. I explained why I deleted it above, in detail. In fact, you have no clue whether I marked the flag(s) on the post as Helpful or not. I simply explained what I did, and that what brought it to my attention were the flag(s).

Comment: Mods do not see who flagged a comment. So the only thing left is to argue the content of the post. And when a mod explains in detail what is wrong with the post, exact flag content is superfluous. @car

Comment: @Andrew Barber: You're right I have no clue. BTW When I commented I had not seen your addendum to your answer. At that point thought the answerer answered part of the question that had not received attention by others, and that the answerer was not being snide and the commenter was not being fair. I still think that. I honestly meant no disrespect to any moderator. If my words were inappropriate, I apologize.